# plugin with id not working studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add google play services library in Android studio.I have added the google play services in build.gradle.

But it is now working for me.I have referred many SO Post regarding to this.But it doesn't solved my problem.

Below I am posted the build.gradle code where I have added the google play services.

[image]

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    apply plugin : 'android'
    dependencies {

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    }


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

}
```

While adding the google play services in dependencies at gradle `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30`. I am getting an error:plugin with id not working.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Post your error properly. Still not got it. or try to change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'` it's worked with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`

Comment: are you sure, you are editing the correct build.gradle ?

Comment: @Blackbelt its correct.I have added play services in build.gradle not in module gradle

Comment: help me to understand. What you posted doesn't look like the module build.gradle. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Blackbelt you are right.it doesn't module build.gradle

Comment: that should explain the error. I think you can't have a dependencies section in the `project build.gradle`, but only in the `module build.gradle`

Comment: @Blackbelt Solved that one.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build.gradle` you have posted seems to be the project configuration. The global project `build.gradle` has the `buildscript` tag and also the comment about not adding application dependencies as can be seen in your question.

There should be another `build.gradle` inside your app module where you should also find something similar to this depending on your version of Android Studio and Gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Place your `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'` inside the app module's `build.gradle` depedencies

Comment: I have added play services in build.gradle not in module gradle

Comment: There should be another `build.gradle` file somewhere in your project. The Google Play Services should be in your app module. The `build.gradle` you have posted is the project configuration as can be seen both by the `buildscript` tag and the comment inside the first `dependencies` tag. Note that you have duplicated `dependencies`. @Naruto

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil yup worked for me.Thak you Dahlgren

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

**Update:**

Think you using wrong gradle file. You must add the above code in the gardle file under app folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your library dependencies in the **build.gradle** file the resides inside your **app** module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
  ...............
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'  
}
```

You should not add these dependencies inside build.gradle file for the root folder

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**Do not place your application dependencies inside the outer build.gradle file they belongin the individual module build.gradle files**